# Crazy Question - Updating Post ID

Tags: posts, id

I know this is a little bizarre but is there a function that can update/modify a post_id automatically when a user updates a post? 
I know there are functions to update publish dates automatically but the ID is so unique, is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not simply, you'd need to act directly on the database and make sure to update all uses of the ID in postmeta and term_relationships, and that wouldn't cover plugins that might have their own tables associating data with a particular post. Why do you even want to update the ID? The ID should be the *one* thing that doesn't change.

Comment: Yeah you should not do that.  Jacob is correct the ID is the one part of a post that should never change.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I have no idea WHY you would want to do this. **IDs are unique for a reason. If you change the ID, I can only see it creating more problems than it solves.** Can you explain why you want to do this? I'm sure the community could give you an alternate solution. But to answer the question, here goes:

No. There is no function that does that. You would need to run some code when the user saves or updates a post. It should be possible though. You could use this action hook in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_function_name_here', 10, 3 );
function my_function_name_here($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before) {
    global $wpdb;

    // this is the custom query
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET ID=[your new ID] WHERE ID = $post_ID"));
}
```

Then inside that function, you can create a custom database query that will change the ID.

**Note: This will fail if the new ID is already in the table, so you may want to check for the new ID's existence first. Or solve the problem in a way that does not attempt to change IDs**

I have to stress that this is not a good way to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve. Hope I helped.

**Update:** The OP posted this as the actual issue: "The problem I have is the devs for a property management theme decided to order the properties by their ID over say, publish date. A client of mine has rental properties that periodically are active and inactive. When we reactivate a property we would like it to be the first listings but because its ordered by ID this can't happen unless we re-enter the property. Right now we are just cloning the property and deleting the original since this gives the cloned property a new ID."

In this case, find the query being used to get all the posts. Instead of using ID as order_by, use these parameters: **'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'order' => 'DESC'**

This will change the query to display the most recently modified post first.

Comment: The problem I have is the devs for a property management theme decided to order the properties by their ID over say, publish date. A client of mine has rental properties that periodically are active and inactive. When we reactivate a property we would like it to be the first listings but because its ordered by ID this can't happen unless we re-enter the property. 
Right now we are just cloning the property and deleting the original since this gives the cloned property a new ID. This is not exactly practical which is why I was looking for an automated process. Theme devs no go.

Comment: It would be much much easier for everybody involved if you just changed the order_by parameter in whatever query is being used to get the posts to use date last updated rather than ID.